# Why is the query running so slow when there are indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I am running a query in SQL Server, and it suddenly started running very slow. Up until yesterday, it used to run in < 1 sec (or max, 3 sec). All of a sudden, today, it now takes 7 - 9 minutes. I believe I have indexes set up properly.

Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE T_INDEX (
    IndexId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [OwnerId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    [TicketId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    [TicketLogId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    [Type] [varchar](20) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [CallId] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [MessageId] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [IndexRawDataId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    --INDEX/SEARCH
    [CallTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IndexMessageId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    [Direction] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Action] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Result] [varchar](30) NULL,
    --GENERAL
    [DefaultFileName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    [TimeElapsedForTransfer] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    [TimeElapsedForIndex] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    [Duration] [int] NULL,
    [HasR] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0), -- HAS RECORDING
    [HasV] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0), -- HAS VOICEMAIL
    [DeletedInd] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    [CompleteInd] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
)
```

And I have indexes defined as such:

```
CREATE INDEX idx__T_INDEX__CallId
  ON RingClone.dbo.T_INDEX (CallId)
GO

CREATE INDEX idx__T_INDEX__CallTime
  ON RingClone.dbo.T_INDEX (CallTime)
GO

CREATE INDEX idx__T_INDEX__MessageId
  ON RingClone.dbo.T_INDEX (MessageId)
GO

CREATE INDEX idx__T_INDEX__OwnerId
  ON RingClone.dbo.T_INDEX (OwnerId)
GO

CREATE INDEX idx_T_INDEX_Dist
  ON RingClone.dbo.T_INDEX (CompleteInd, DeletedInd)
  INCLUDE (CallId, MessageId, OwnerId)
GO

CREATE INDEX nci_wi_T_INDEX_4E1CEC32C8F3DA763461240A854A7891
  ON RingClone.dbo.T_INDEX (TicketId)
GO
```

My Query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @ownerId varchar(20)
DECLARE @type varchar(20)
DECLARE @dateFrom datetime
DECLARE @dateTo datetime

SELECT TOP 50 T_INDEX.*
    FROM T_INDEX
    WHERE OwnerId=@ownerId
     AND [Type]=@type
     AND CallTime >= @dateFrom
     AND CallTime <= @dateTo
    ORDER BY CallTime DESC
```

There are around 4 million records in this table. And the fragmentation on all the indexes for this table is < 2%. I just updated around 50K rows (changed the `OwnerId`) before I noticed the slowness. But I immediately re-indexed the indexes afterward. Could this update have something to do with the sudden slowness? Do I have my indexes set up correctly for this query? If I combined `OwnerId`, 'Type`, and 'CallTime`, would that cause the query to run faster? Is there something else that I can do to get this back running fast?

Comment: What does "show query plan" in enterprise manager show?

Comment: That looks like a "catch-all" query; they can be notoriously slow. Gail Shaw did an excellent article on these: [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Comment: Also, you have a `TOP`, but where is your `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There are no null date ranges, so I took the "null-checking" out. Also, I left out the `ORDER BY` clause by mistake, so I have added it back into the question. However, even with the removal of the "catch-all", it is still running 7-9 minutes.

Comment: Start refactoring. Type is a varchar - that should be an int with a separate lookup table. Varchar comparisons are always a lot slower than anything else and I coubt you need a varchar(20) to code all possible times. Same with the other data -looks like a VERY bad deisgn for space and op usage.

Comment: What completeness, what are the datatypes of the respective parameters/variables? Could you include a `DECLARE` statement?

Comment: @TomTom, I get what you are saying about `Type` running better if it were an int. However, I do not have control over that part of the app. And from what I'm told, other parts of the app rely on it being `VARCHAR`. But I think you are right about the param sniffing.

Comment: @Larnu, sorry about that. I was trying to be concise. I have added the params now.

Comment: Also provide or analyse some statistics. I would assume this is a history table but rarely queries for longer timeframes, so CallTime is the primary filter, liklely ALWAYS existing (because you basically never want too old data on a report or so). Queries exist in context - which we lack. Dpeneing on actual usage and calls per owner, CallTime,OwnerId may be the optimal index (with Type a  possible third field).

Answer (score 2):

> AND (@dateFrom IS NULL OR CallTime >= @dateFrom)

Please make proper queries - either @dateFrom is null or not. Generate the SQL dynamically.

Alternativel mark the query optimize for unknown.

You experience liekly what is known as parameter sniffing where the query plan is determined once and reused. And not updated when a different query plan makes more sense.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: I think this is what was happening. After running a few different versions of the query, it "magically" started running in < 3 sec.

Comment: That is typical - it basically gets stuck with a selective index (base on first parameter set) which totally is bad for another parameter set, but hey, let's reuse a query plan.

Comment: What do you mean by "mark the query optimize for unknown"?

Comment: @MattSpinks https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature/ - new feature, optimize basically for a stable but not really super efficient plan. Not a good general solution but worth a try.

Answer (score -1):

For this query:

```
SELECT TOP 50 T_INDEX.*
FROM T_INDEX
WHERE OwnerId = @ownerId AND
     [Type] = @type AND
     CallTime >= @dateFrom AND
     CallTime <= @dateTo
ORDER BY CallTime DESC;
```

The optimal index is a composite index on `(OwnerId, Type, CallTime)`.  The first two columns could be swapped.

You only have two candidate indexes for the query, `(OwnerId)` and `(CallTime)` (although SQL Server may not catch that one).  Neither is optimal.

Another potential problem is that the execution plan might be cached.  For instance, if the code is in a stored procedure, and the procedure is tested on an empty table, it might cache an execution plan using no indexes.  That is why `with (recompile)` is often used for queries in stored procedures.

Comment: Actually no, this is not the optimal index for all.... hm.... combinations of null or not null that can exist.

Comment: @TomTom . . . I have no idea what you are referring to.  This is exactly the query specified by the OP, and it has `NULL` checks only on the date range.

Comment: I believe what TomTom is trying to say, Gordon, is that SQL Server can behave quite poorly when providing nullable parameters, especially where there are multiple of them. So, as both `@dateFrom` and `@dateTo` have the potential to be `NULL` this can play havok with the query estimator. I posted a link under the question to an article that discusses this at length. I don't think it was worth the downvote, but it is something that needs to be considered.

Comment: @Larnu . . . And that is pretty irrelevant to the use of the index.  The purpose of `CallTime` in the index is to cover the `WHERE` clause.  The first two columns can be looked up directly.  I don't think there will be much confusion with the direct lookups.

Comment: "The optimal index" may actually ahve all 3 fields in different order depending on parameter. WHich is why the optimal index depends on which parameter combo actually happens. I have similar queries and in my case the FromDate (which likely is a DateTime) actually is most selective as there are very few query types.

Comment: The concept is quite well explained in the article I linked (it's worth a read Gordon if it's not something you're familiar with), however, the OP has since advised that the parameters don't need to have a `NULL` value, rendering the entire point moot for their needs.

Comment: @TomTom . . . I find it hard to image a real case where the equality conditions would be anything worse than neutral -- and the optimizer should pick up the index with the two equality conditions over other indexes. As for parameter sniffing, that was actually alluded to in the answer, albeit with a solution that you might not prefer.

Comment: Actually beginnner mistake: there likely are not a lof ot call types and it is very likely that the query is time coded (with or without call type). i.e. Type goes last. Owner or date first must be analyzed - date may be WAY more selective. Wth recompile is not a good choice depending on query number. Recompiles are expensive, optimize for unknown may work better. Many things wrong.